# Error: Cannot find module 'update-notifier'. I cannot install any NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js

There is a similar question on StackOverFlow but it was unhelpful and it wasn't answered. I have been working on a project and I currently am receiving this error.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'update-notifier'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:29:19
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:92:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
```

If I type **any** command that includes **npm** it returns the same error, I can't install anything.

I have tried to uninstall/re-install NodeJS with homebrew but nothing changed from trying that.

Comment: Show how you install it. Do you install packages globally or locally?

Comment: Solution: I had to re-install and delete EVERYTHING. Follow this tutorial:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x

Comment: No clue what caused this error, it happened out of nowhere. It would appear on every project of mine that included NodeJS